# MySQLdb module is not installed on my python

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

I am trying to install the mysqldb module in my python2.7 ubuntu. I am using the following ways to install

```
    $ tar -xvf MySQL-python-1.2.2.tar
    $ cd MySQL-python-1.2.2
    $ sudo python setup.py build
    $ sudo python setup.py install
```

then i am going to import the module. It shows the following error.

```
    import MySQLdb
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

I have also tried to install by using apt-get and pip. there is no way it shows the same above import error. Could you please help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: No. I have just tried in terminal only

Comment: I have installed that package with that version and the only error I had was a package dependency, but after I have installed that I could import it without any problem following the instructions you wrote. So I only can think that Python can't find the package in its path.

Comment: There are no errors when you install MySQL-python？

Comment: yes.There is no error while installing

Comment: @balaraman if you try to do a `sys.path.append(path)` with `path = the_path_where_you_are`. Do you still see the error?